# Modified Gravity against Dark Matter

Tags: dark-matter, modified-gravity

I am looking for examples of Modified Gravity theories that have been developed with the aim of dispensing dark matter, besides Milgrom's [MOND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modified_Newtonian_dynamics), Bekenstein's [TeVeS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor%E2%80%93vector%E2%80%93scalar_gravity), and the recent relativistic version of MOND ([RMOND](https://arxiv.org/abs/2007.00082)) by Skordis and Zlosnik.

Are there any other examples of similar attempts in the recent history of physics?